# How to create a process which polls at an interval?

Tags: loops, recursion, erlang, repeat

I'm trying to create a process that checks a dir every few seconds/milliseconds and process the files in it, is the below acceptable in Erlang?

```
init(Dir) ->    loop(Dir).

loop(Dir) ->
    check_dir(Dir),
    spawn(fun() -> do_something(File) end),
    timer:sleep(5).
    loop(Dir).
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in many ways. A good first one to try is to use [`timer:apply_interval/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4). You set an interval and the function will *apply* (aka call) you function at each interval.

```
apply_interval(10, cool_module_name, check_dir_and_notify, [File]).
```

The function call above will call `check_dir_and_notify` every 10 ms. It will continue forever unless you cancel it.